# Hyperjaxb3: Create lookup table from enumeration element

Tags: hibernate, xsd, jaxb, hyperjaxb

I have an xsd file which includes an element with an enumeration constraint:

```
<xs:complexType name="Request">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="CommsAddress" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="CommsAddressType">
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                    <xs:enumeration value="EMAIL"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="PHONE"/>
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:element>
        ...
```

I would like the `CommsAddressType` field in the generated Java class to be a generated enum with the values `EMAIL` and `PHONE`. In turn, I would like Hibernate to automatically generate my database schema with a `CommsAddressType` table containing two rows with the values `EMAIL` and `PHONE`. The `Request` table can then simply reference these with a `CommsAddressTypeId` column.

Currently, Hyperjaxb3 generates my `Request` class with a `CommsAddressType` field of type `String`:

```
@XmlElement(name="CommsAddressType")
protected String commsAddressType
```

and the schema is generated so that the `Request` table has a `CommsAddressType` column of type `VARCHAR`. This will obviously result in a lot of unnecessary duplicated data.

Is there any way of achieving what I described above? Also, as I am exposing the xsd to my customer, I would like to avoid including any jaxb or hyperjaxb tags in the schema if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** I'm the author of [Hyperjaxb](https://github.com/highsource/hyperjaxb3).

If you make your enumerated types to become enums in Java, Hyperjaxb will handle them as enums, not as strings. For this you can, for instance, customize your simple type with:

```
<jaxb:typesafeEnumClass/>
```

See this [example](https://github.com/highsource/hyperjaxb3/blob/master/ejb/tests/enum/src/main/resources/schema.xsd#L60).

Hyperjaxb will map corrsponding properties as `@Enumerated`.

No, you can't generate a lookup table but you can customize how the enum is mapped in the database. For instance, you can make it mapped as `EnumType.ORDINAL`:

```
<hj:basic><orm:enumerated>ORDINAL</orm:enumerated></hj:basic>
```

[Example](https://github.com/highsource/hyperjaxb3/blob/master/ejb/tests/enum/src/main/resources/schema.xsd#L43).

Actually, with enums you don't really need lookup tables for JPA. JPA will map enums correctly according to the speified `EnumType` mapping.

But you may need a lookup table for your own purposes - like being able to produce human-readable values in joined queries.

In this case I'd recommend mapping the enum as `ORDINAL` and adding a lookup table plus corresponding foreign keys on your own DDL scripts.

And yes, you can do all of the described customizations in a separate bindings file (normally `bindings.xjb`), you don't have to do it directly in the schema. See test projects [here](https://github.com/highsource/hyperjaxb3/blob/master/ejb/tests), there is plenty of examples. Just look for `*.xjb` files in `src/main/resources` directories.